TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter')
In a previous question, I asked help to implement this Azure Maps Animations sample with TypeScript: https://samples.azuremaps.com/animations/animate-marker-along-path
I understood that I should merge 'azure-maps-control' and 'azure-maps-animations' but I still have issues.
At start-up, all files are loaded but these errors occurs:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter')
    at azure-maps-animations.js:1101:23 at azure-maps-animations.js:3424:2
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'moveAlongRoute')
        at main.ts:21:59

Here are my files, if you were able to understand what the issue is.
Index.htm:
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/requirejs/require.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./config.js" defer></script>
    <link href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/3/atlas.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap"></div>
</body>

Config.js:
require.config({
  baseUrl: './js',
  paths: {
    'azure-maps-control': 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/3/atlas'
    ,'azure-maps-animations': '../lib/azure-maps/azure-maps-animations'
  }
});

require(['main'], function(main) {
  console.log('...end.');
});

Main.ts:
import * as mapControl from 'azure-maps-control';
import * as azanimations from 'azure-maps-animations';

namespace atlas {
    // Enums
    export const AuthenticationType = mapControl.AuthenticationType;
    export const ControlPosition = mapControl.ControlPosition;
    export const ControlStyle = mapControl.ControlStyle;

    // Classes
    export const EventManager = mapControl.EventManager;
    export const HtmlMarker = mapControl.HtmlMarker;
    export const Map = mapControl.Map;
    export const Pixel = mapControl.Pixel;
    export const Popup = mapControl.Popup;
    export const PopupTemplate = mapControl.PopupTemplate;
    export const Shape = mapControl.Shape;
}

namespace atlas.animations {
    export const moveAlongRoute = azanimations.animations.moveAlongRoute;
    export type GroupAnimation = azanimations.animations.GroupAnimation;
    export type FrameBasedAnimationTimer = azanimations.animations.FrameBasedAnimationTimer;
    export type PlayableAnimation = azanimations.animations.PlayableAnimation;
}

namespace atlas.control {
    export const CompassControl = mapControl.control.CompassControl;
    export const ControlBase = mapControl.control.ControlBase;
    export const PitchControl = mapControl.control.PitchControl;
    export const ScaleControl = mapControl.control.ScaleControl;
    export const StyleControl = mapControl.control.StyleControl;
    export const TrafficControl = mapControl.control.TrafficControl;
    export const TrafficLegendControl = mapControl.control.TrafficLegendControl;
    export const ZoomControl = mapControl.control.ZoomControl;

    export type StyleControlEvents = mapControl.control.StyleControlEvents;
}

namespace atlas.data {
    export const Feature = mapControl.data.Feature;
    export const FeatureCollection = mapControl.data.FeatureCollection;
    export const GeometryCollection = mapControl.data.GeometryCollection;
    export const LineString = mapControl.data.LineString;
    export const MercatorPoint = mapControl.data.MercatorPoint;
    export const MultiLineString = mapControl.data.MultiLineString;
    export const MultiPoint = mapControl.data.MultiPoint;
    export const MultiPolygon = mapControl.data.MultiPolygon;
    export const Point = mapControl.data.Point;
    export const Polygon = mapControl.data.Polygon;
    
    export type Position = mapControl.data.Position;
}

namespace atlas.internal {
    export const EventEmitter = mapControl.internal.EventEmitter;
}

namespace atlas.layer {
    // Layers from both Control and Animations
    export const BubbleLayer = mapControl.layer.BubbleLayer;
    export const HeatMapLayer = mapControl.layer.HeatMapLayer;
    export const ImageLayer = mapControl.layer.ImageLayer;
    export const Layer = mapControl.layer.Layer;
    export const LineLayer = mapControl.layer.LineLayer;
    export const PolygonExtrusionLayer = mapControl.layer.PolygonExtrusionLayer;
    export const PolygonLayer = mapControl.layer.PolygonLayer;
    export const SymbolLayer = mapControl.layer.SymbolLayer;
    export const TileLayer = mapControl.layer.TileLayer;
    export const WebGLLayer = mapControl.layer.WebGLLayer;
    
    export const AnimatedTileLayer = azanimations.layer.AnimatedTileLayer;
}

namespace atlas.math {
    export type AccelerationUnits = mapControl.math.AccelerationUnits
    export const AffineTransform = mapControl.math.AffineTransform;
    export type AreaUnits = mapControl.math.AreaUnits;
    export type DistanceUnits = mapControl.math.DistanceUnits;
    export type SpeedUnits = mapControl.math.SpeedUnits;
    export type TimeUnits = mapControl.math.TimeUnits;
}

namespace atlas.source {
    export const DataSource = mapControl.source.DataSource;
    export const ElevationTileSource = mapControl.source.ElevationTileSource;
    export const Source = mapControl.source.Source;
    export const VectorTileSource = mapControl.source.VectorTileSource;
}

var anim: any;
var map: any;

function main() {

    try {
        console.log("main");

        map = new atlas.Map("myMap", {
            center: [-122.345, 47.615],
            zoom: 14,
            view: 'Auto',
            authOptions: {...}
        });

        map.events.add('click', function () {
            anim.play();
        });

        //Wait until the map resources are ready.
        map.events.add('ready', function () {

            //Load a custom image icon into the map resources.
            map.imageSprite.createFromTemplate('arrow-icon', 'marker-arrow', 'teal', '#fff').then(function () {

                //Create data sources and add them to the map.
                var lineSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                var pinSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add([lineSource, pinSource]);

                //Create a layer to render the path.
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(lineSource, undefined, {
                    strokeColor: 'DodgerBlue',
                    strokeWidth: 3
                }));

                var routePoints = [
                    new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-122.34758, 47.62155]), { _timestamp: new Date('Tue, 18 Aug 2020 00:53:53 GMT').getTime() }),
                    new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-122.34764, 47.61859]), { _timestamp: new Date('Tue, 18 Aug 2020 00:54:53 GMT').getTime() })
                ];

                //Extract the positions to highlight the full route on the map as a line.
                var path: atlas.data.Position[] = [];

                routePoints.forEach(f => {
                    path.push(f.geometry.coordinates);
                });

                //Create a line for the path and add it to the data source.
                lineSource.add(new atlas.data.LineString(path));

                //Create a layer to render a symbol which we will animate.
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(pinSource, undefined, {
                    iconOptions: {
                        //Pass in the id of the custom icon that was loaded into the map resources.
                        image: 'arrow-icon',

                        //Anchor the icon to the center of the image.
                        anchor: 'center',

                        //Rotate the icon based on the rotation property on the point data.
                        //The arrow icon being used in this case points down, so we have to rotate it 180 degrees.
                        rotation: ['+', 180, ['get', 'heading']],

                        //Have the rotation align with the map.
                        rotationAlignment: 'map',

                        //For smoother animation, ignore the placement of the icon. This skips the label collision calculations and allows the icon to overlap map labels. 
                        ignorePlacement: true,

                        //For smoother animation, allow symbol to overlap all other symbols on the map.
                        allowOverlap: true
                    },
                    textOptions: {
                        //For smoother animation, ignore the placement of the text. This skips the label collision calculations and allows the text to overlap map labels.
                        ignorePlacement: true,

                        //For smoother animation, allow text to overlap all other symbols on the map.
                        allowOverlap: true
                    }
                }));

                //Create a pin and wrap with the shape class and add to data source.
                var pin = new atlas.Shape(routePoints[0]);
                pinSource.add(pin);

                try {
                    //Create the animation.
                    anim = atlas.animations.moveAlongRoute(routePoints, pin, { 
                        //Specify the property that contains the timestamp.
                        //timestampProperty: 'timestamp',

                        captureMetadata: true,
                        loop: false,
                        reverse: false,
                        rotationOffset: 0,
                        
                        speedMultiplier: 60,
                        map: undefined,
                        zoom: 15,
                        pitch: 45,
                        rotate: true
                    });

                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error initializing game:', error);
                }

                console.log("done");
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing game:', error);
    }
}

function ready(fn: () => void) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}

ready(() => {
    console.log("addEventListener");
    main();
});


Reviewing my code, it now seems that my issues comes from the fact I use "module": "AMD" in my tsconfig.json, I used it because I like working with RequireJS and it seemed a good.  As Animations module has a reference to azmaps, I believe now that RequireJS is unable to load it.  I tried writing adapters to adapt both azmaps and atlas   and made them work with RequireJS but I didn't managed to do that either.    I will continue trying later but if anyone has an idea on that, thanks a lot   :-|
